# This is my first ever attempt to write a SQL statement so please bear with me

Tags: sql, excel

I have written the below statement exactly as it appears in the example I researched.

I'm trying to get 2 worksheets to combine into one (actually I will need to ultimately combine 71 sheets into one). The actual file path for the file is `C:\Users\Roxanne\Wipledger Task Acc19.xlsx`, however, I have tried this and it still doesn't work.

```
Select *
From "C:\Wipledger Task Acc19.xlsx"."Sheet1" 
Union
Select *
From "C:\Wipledger Task Acc19.xlsx"."Sheet2"
```

Comment: Please tag DB and show some data. You need to load these files in DB first. You can not query excel files directly using SQL.

Comment: "the example I researched"...is there a link to that example you can post, then we have some idea of what the overall context is?

Comment: P.S. What does "doesn't work" mean, exactly? Give us a clear description of what is / isn't happening when you try to execute it, any error messages / unexpected outputs, etc. Also, are you executing these commands from SQL Server, or some other environment? It's really unclear what exactly is going on or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Power Query in Excel or Power BI can do this.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605

Comment: The title of your question is not helpful for someone searching this formum for answers to a problem. Please edit it to reflect your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't do the job for your kind of task. Check to use Power Query which is made to do what you wanna do.